# Get implicit results made available from a PL/SQL block or procedure without the use of OUT ref cursor parameters

Tags: python, cx-oracle

After calling a stored procedure in Oracle version below 12, I am not able to get implicit results made available from a PL/SQL block or procedure without the use of `OUT` ref cursor parameters.

The `cx_Oracle` version I am using is 5.2.1. Python version is 2.7.

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(con_param)
cursor_e = connection.cursor() 
cursor_e.callproc('my_proc_name',(tstart,tend,falseVar))
```

I have even tried this solution

```
        plsql = """declare 
            c1 sys_refcursor;           
            begin
                    open c1 for 
                    execute my_proc(tstart,tend,falseVar)
                    dbms_sql.return_result(c1);
            end;"""
        cursor_e.execute(plsql)

        for ix, resultSet in enumerate(cursor_e.getimplicitresults()):
            print("Result Set #" + str(ix + 1))
            for row in resultSet:
                print(row)
            print()
```

I am getting the below error with above code.
Caught Error: ORA-06550: line 5, column 14:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "my_proc_name" when expecting one of the following:

. ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
    <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between using || multiset member submultiset The symbol "." was substituted for "my_proc_name" to continue.

When i changed the above code little bit

```
         plsql = """declare 
            c1 sys_refcursor;           
            begin
                    open c1 for 
                    my_proc(tstart,tend,falseVar);
                    dbms_sql.return_result(c1);
            end;"""
        cursor_e.execute(plsql)
```

I am getting the below error

Caught Error: ORA-06550: line 5, column 6:
PLS-00222: no function with name 'my_proc_name' exists in this scope
ORA-06550: line 4, column 16:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 6, column 15:
PLS-00302: component 'RETURN_RESULT' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 6, column 6:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

This procedure is around 300 lines with lot of logic. i can't just get SQL out and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit results are only available in Oracle 12.1 and cx_Oracle 5.3 (not yet released). Prior to that you must in fact use REF cursor parameters.

Here is an example using implicit results.

```
# using a PL/SQL anonymous block but this could also
# be a stored procedure
cursor.execute("""
        declare
            c1 sys_refcursor;
            c2 sys_refcursor;
        begin

            open c1 for
            select * from Table1;

            dbms_sql.return_result(c1);

            open c2 for
            select * from Table2;

            dbms_sql.return_result(c2);

        end;""")

# display results
for ix, resultSet in enumerate(cursor.getimplicitresults()):
    print("Result Set #" + str(ix + 1))
    for row in resultSet:
        print(row)
    print()
```

Comment: Sure. For implicit results or for REF cursor?

Comment: Getting cursor of procedure without the use of OUT ref cursor parameters. Stored procedure i am trying to cursor is defined as follows.  create or replace procedure my_proc_name (start_dt varchar2, end_dt varchar2, debug boolean)   Thank you , i appreciate your help.

Comment: Please review my code and let me know if i am calling procedure correctly. Thank you.  plsql = """declare
               c1 sys_refcursor;           
              begin
               open c1 for 
     execute my_proc_name(tstart,tend,falseVar)
     dbms_sql.return_result(c1);
              end;"""
   cursor_ebay.execute(plsql)
   
   for ix, resultSet in enumerate(cursor_ebay.getimplicitresults()):
       print("Result Set #" + str(ix + 1))
       for row in resultSet:
           print(row)
          print()

Comment: Its pretty hard to read that code. Generally you want to open a select statement, not call a stored procedure. If you call a stored procedure you will need to use the ref cursor directly in it. Please update your question with the code so that it is readable. You will also need to include what is going on in your other procedure.